# How to keep the value of dynamic drop down selected after form submission?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please help me to show the selected email after form submission.Please Have a on the code mentioned below:

```
<?php
    $query= mysqli_query($conn," SELECT email FROM register");
    $options="";
    $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0)
    {
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
       {
         $options = $options."<option>$row[0]</option>";
       }
   }
?>
<select name="email" id="email">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="">SELECT EMAIL</option>
<?php echo $options;?>
</select>
```

Comment: Where is you form tag? Add a check if form posted and posted email is same add attribute `selected` top option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by selectable your Dropdown option

Try this

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$query= mysqli_query($conn," SELECT email FROM register");
$options="";
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0){
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     $options.= '<option '.(($row[0]==$email)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$row[0].'</option>';
   }
}
?>
<select name="email" id="email">
   <option value="" disabled="" selected="">SELECT EMAIL</option>
   <?php echo $options;?>
</select>
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: Sir, I had tried this code but it is showing following error- *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'*, please help me.

Comment: Dear @GurpreetKaur I have just edited my anser replace the line of while loop of this $options.= '<option '.(($row[0]==$email)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$row[0].'</option>';

Comment: Welcome Dear @GurpreetKaur

Answer (score 2):

```
    <select name="email" id="email">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">SELECT EMAIL</option>
    <?php
    $query= mysqli_query($conn," SELECT email FROM register");
    $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0)
    {
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
       {
         echo "<option value='<?=$row[0]?>'><?= $row[0]?></option>";
       }
   }
     ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: thanx for this answer